# How to add new code in telescope

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I want to add activity panel. how to do it?? please help.. I am new to telescope. how to change particular form like edit user form and want to create new page for activity panel.. is activity panel already present in telescope. and as well as I want to know that is telescope having admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

I only konw that the first user of your telescope is admin. If you want to change the form, you can learn about the third package of aldeed:autoform.
https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform